# raty stars not showing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raty

I would like to use [raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty) for rating the users of my Rails 5.1.6 application and found [Elizabeth Le's documentation](https://medium.com/@elizabethlemk/using-jquery-raty-with-ruby-on-rails-2f1ab60c81c5) on Raty and Ruby on Rails. As suggested in that documentation, I went to the GitHub raty's page and I copied `star-half.png`, `star-off.png` and `star-on.png` in `app/assets/images` and `jquery.raty.js` in `app/assets/javascripts`. Then I added the following code in `/app/views/users/show.html.erb`:

```
<% if !Review.exists?(reviewer_id: current_user.id, reviewed_id: @user.id) && current_user != @user %>
  <h2> Rate this user </h2>
  <%= form_for(current_user.active_reviews.build) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :reviewed_id, value: @user.id %></div>
    <div id=“rating-form”>
      <label> Rating </label>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit your rating", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`Review` is an association between a user and another user, having `reviewer_id`, `reviewed_id` and `rating` as attributes. 
In `app/assets/javascrits/custom.js` I added instead the following javascript code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  $("#rating-form").raty({
    path: "/assets/",
    scoreName: "review[rating]"
  });

});
```

The stars however do not show up. 
I tried to use as path `path: "/assets/images"` and to add `//= require jquery.raty` to `application.js` with no results. I even tried to add the jquery code in view, included in a `<script>` tag at the very bottom of the page, but nothing changed. 
I also tried to download the images and the `jquery.raty.js` file from [jqueryscript.net](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Full-featured-Star-Rating-Plugin-For-jQuery-Raty.html), but this did not change the result.